# How to assign proxy request Store result to Tree in extjs?

Tags: extjs

I am very new to extjs and I am trying to build tree using API request.

Below is what I tried but its not working.

```
Ext.define('LevelModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        {name: 'text', type: 'string'}
    ]
});


var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'LevelModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'API CALL',
        method:'GET',
        reader: {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'data',
            totalProperty : 'total',
            successProperty: 'success'
        },
        root: {
            type: 'async'
        },
        autoLoad: false
    } 
});


var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: "30%",
    height: "100%",
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    useArrows: true
});
```

This is my response from API

```
{
    "data": [
        "AbsaInfrastructure",
        "Macro",
        "Africa",
        "IBD"
    ],
    "total": 4,
    "success": true,
    "serverMessage": null
}
```

Result of data should be the tree nodes.

Please help me to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some things missing in your returning data. I would recommend looking at the documentation of ExtJS how to use TreePanels: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel

Comment: Yes, But that I am not able to figure out what is missing.

Comment: Your data is a flat array, but the data expects object literals like `{text: 'AbsaInfrastructure', leaf: true}`. Look at the code example in the linked docs. ;)

Comment: Sorry for wrong data post. I corrected it.